# How to position a vertical menu as nested <ul> under horizontal parent <li>

Tags: html, css, html-lists

We're really close to solving this one and just need a little help to ties things off. Everything works fine, but how do we get the nested 'ul' to display relative to it's parent 'li' (ie. directly below parent li)?

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul id="continent">
        <li><a href="#">Europe</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">CountryA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CountryB</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CountryC</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Middle East</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">CountryD</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CountryE</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CountryF</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Africa</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">CountryG</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CountryH</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CountryI</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Asia</a>
            <ul>
            <li><a href="#">CountryJ</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CountryK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CountryL</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

And here the CSS:

```
ul#continent{position:relative;}
ul#continent li{display:inline; list-style-type:none;}

ul#continent li ul{display:none;}
ul#continent li:hover {cursor:pointer;}
ul#continent li:hover ul{display:block; position:absolute; top:52px; margin:-20px 0 0 -10px; padding:20px; width:160px; z-index:999;}
ul#continent li:hover ul li{display:block; padding:3px 10px;}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `float:left;` and `float:none;` instead of `display:inline;`. And than play with `margin` or `padding`.

```
ul#continent li{float:left; list-style-type:none;}
ul#continent li:hover ul li{float:none; padding:3px 10px;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L5Ts5/)**

In demo 2 you see it with some `background-color`, `width & height`, `margin` and `text-align` changes in the css how it looks like.

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/L5Ts5/3/)**

Comment: Thanks C Travel. Works a dream. Oh so close..!!

Comment: No Problem Richard! Happy to help!

Answer (score 0):

Move the `position: relative` from `ul#continent` to the first level `li`s This will allow you to position the nested `ul`s relative to the corresponding `li`

```css
ul#continent li {
    position:relative;
}
ul#continent li:hover ul {
    left: 0;
}
```

Reducing `top`, `margin` and `padding` brings the `ul` closer to the `li`.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H7Nva/)